# slideshow of images continously in android

Tags: android, imageview, slideshow

I want to display images continuously with 5 seconds gap using imageview in android.

I have tried following code

```
String[] Img_data = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

   Cursor imgcursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,    Img_data,null,null, null); 

         if(imgcursor!=null && img_cursor.getCount()>0){

           while(!imgcursor.isAfterLast()){

            imgcursor.moveToFirst();

              String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

              imageview.setImageUri(Uri.parse(filepath);
              imgcursor.moveToNext();
           }

         }
```

Please send me the appropriate answer for this question.

Comment: You can use the handler for this. Use PostDelay method of handler for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Handler for this as below :-

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);

final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

            Utility.getInstance(getActivity()).displayImage(mImageUrlsTop.get(mCounterTop++), mImageViewTop, mProgressBarTop);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);                          
    }
};
```

Here displayImage is the my function to display image for provided URL and Imageview & mImageUrlsTop is the arraylist of ImageUrl's.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 private Runnable updateImageThread = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime1;

                updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 5000);
    // set images to imageview  here as per your need

                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }

        };


// call this thread like this
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
customHandler.postDelayed(updateImageThread, 0);
```